I cannot add data to the database in Laravel
public function projects(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ]);

        
        $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');

        $project = new Projects();
        $project->title = $validatedData['title'];
        $project->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $project->image = $imagePath; 
        $project->save();
    }

    $projects = Projects::all();

    return view('home/pages/projects', [
        'projects' => $projects
    ]);
}

HomeController.php
Route::post('/projeler', [HomeController::class, 'projects'])->name('projects');

Web.php
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'image',
        'description',
        'slug',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];
}

Projects.php as a Model.
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
    <button onclick=showDialog() class="btn btn-primary">Add Project</button>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close d-flex justify-content-end"  onclick="closeDialog()">&times;</span>
        <h2>Add Project</h2>
        <form action="{{ route('projects') }}" method="POST">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectName">Proje Adı:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectName" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectDescription">Proje Açıklaması:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="projectDescription" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="projectImage">Proje Görseli:</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="projectImage" name="image">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function showDialog() {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function closeDialog() {
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

Projects.twig file.
What I tried to do is when the user presses the button called 'Add Project' a pop-up opens. Here, there are title, description and image upload fields. When the user fills them in and clicks the Add button, I try to return the projects.twig page and retrieve and display all the projects in the database with the Projects::all() method. I added it to the database manually, there is no problem in displaying the data or I do not receive any errors when I press the add button. But it does not add the data to the database.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

So $project->save(); should save it? Do you also need to commit the change in your framework?

This question lacks a lot of detail. What is the actual question here? You've only dumped a wall of code and text... What is not working? Which errors are you actually receiving? [ask] - How to create a [mre]

You should have enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in the form if you are trying to submit a form.
Check this example
